# How to change font of the dropdown menu of the paginator listing the number of pages to be bigger?

Tags: html, css, typescript, sass, pagination

Im making a paginator and its functional but the rows per page options has a font listing the numbers 10 and 20 with a really small font? How do I make it bigger?

I tried using something like this but it's not working. I'm using a paginator with a treetable by the way.

```
.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-pages .ui-paginator-rpp-options{
    font-size: 100px !important;
}


.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-pages .ui-paginator-page{ 
    min-width: 2.5em !important; 
}
```

(This bottom code works for something else)

Comment: Hi Sailesh. It's likely that the class or nesting of elements isn't quite correct. Are you able to add your HTML markup, please?